# In textmate Is there a way to select the method/function the caret is in?

Tags: textmate

In textmate, I know I can select a few different things using the built-in select keyboard shortcuts, but I haven't seen any way to select the current method that I am in. I commonly find myself wanting to delete or move whole methods in Ruby but currently the only way to do it is by selecting the whole thing line by line. Does anyone know of a bundle that offers this?